# axios.post request gets 404

Tags: reactjs, go, axios, go-gin

Client side(React/axios.post) failed to post to server side api (Golang/gin) with status code 404.
I want to make this post request success.

Following curl success to write data in mysql table

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"title":"bbb", "content":"bbb"}' localhost:4000/api/post
```

But, in case of axios.post, 404 error occurs.

This is target source code.

```
interface ArticleState {
  title: string;
  content: string;
  redirect: boolean;
}

class Post extends React.Component<{}, ArticleState> {
  constructor(props: {}) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: '',
      content: '',
      redirect: false,
    };

    this.handleChangeTitle = this.handleChangeTitle.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeContent = this.handleChangeContent.bind(this);
    this.setRedirect = this.setRedirect.bind(this);
    this.renderRedirect = this.renderRedirect.bind(this);
  }

  handleChangeTitle(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    this.setState({title: e.currentTarget.value});
  }

  handleChangeContent(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    this.setState({content: e.currentTarget.value});
  }

  setRedirect() {
    this.setState({
      redirect: true,
    });

    const data = {title: this.state.title, content: this.state.content};
    axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/post', data).then(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }

  renderRedirect = () => {
    if (this.state.redirect) {
      return <Redirect to="/post/finish" />;
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Container text style={{marginTop: '3em'}}>
        <Form onSubmit={this.setRedirect}>
          <Form.Input
            label="Title"
            name="title"
            value={this.state.title}
            onChange={this.handleChangeTitle}
          />
          <Form.Field
            label="Content"
            name="content"
            value={this.state.content}
            control="textarea"
            onChange={this.handleChangeContent}
          />
          {this.renderRedirect()}
          <Form.Button content="Submit" />
        </Form>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

```
type Article struct {
    ID      int    `json:"id"`
    TITLE   string `json:"title"`
    CONTENT string `json:"content"`
}

var articles []Article

func main() {

    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user:password@tcp(localhost:3306)/article")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer db.Close()

    router := gin.Default()

    api := router.Group("/api")
    {
        api.POST("/post", func(c *gin.Context) {
            var article Article
            c.BindJSON(&article)
            c.Header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            c.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            ins, err := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO articles(title,content) VALUES(?,?)")
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            ins.Exec(article.TITLE, article.CONTENT)
            c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"status": "ok"})
        })
    }
    router.Run(":4000")
}
```

I expect axios.post success to request, but actually failed with 404 status.

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:4000/api/post 404 (Not Found)
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:4000/api/post' 
from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested 
resource.
createError.js:17 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:80)
```

Comment: You should fix the CORS issue, it clearly doesn't help getting a right response code.

Comment: Your server must set the right CORS headers in order for the browser to make the POST request. For this, your server needs to respond to `OPTIONS` requests sent by the browser as well.

Comment: I already added `c.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")` in server side code. But still same error occurs.

Comment: Your server only responds to POST requests, as seen with `api.POST`, but it should also respond to OPTIONS requests as well.

Comment: I got it. Issue was resolved. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working code that I tested:

```
type Article struct {
    ID      int    `json:"id"`
    TITLE   string `json:"title"`
    CONTENT string `json:"content"`
}

var articles []Article

func main() {

    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:111111@tcp(localhost:3306)/article")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer db.Close()

    router := gin.Default()

    router.Use(cors.New(cors.Config{
        AllowOrigins:     []string{"*"},
        AllowMethods:     []string{"GET", "POST", "OPTIONS"},
        AllowHeaders:     []string{"Content-Type", "Content-Length", "Accept-Encoding", "X-CSRF-Token", "Authorization", "accept", "origin", "Cache-Control", "X-Requested-With"},
        ExposeHeaders:    []string{"Content-Length"},
        AllowCredentials: true,
        AllowOriginFunc: func(origin string) bool {
            return true
        },
        MaxAge: 15 * time.Second,
    }))
    api := router.Group("/api")
    {

        api.POST("/post", func(c *gin.Context) {
            var article Article
            c.BindJSON(&article)
            ins, err := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO articles(title,content) VALUES(?,?)")
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            ins.Exec(article.TITLE, article.CONTENT)
            c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"status": "ok"})
        })
    }
    router.Run(":4000")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says the request 'has been blocked by CORS policy', which is short for '[Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)' and is a security measure implemented by the browser. The solution is to modify your server to return the correct 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header.

Comment: I already added `c.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")` in server side code. But still same error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

After I added some codes in server side, issue was resolved.

```
        api.POST("/post", func(c *gin.Context) {
            c.Header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            c.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            // add 
            c.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")
            var article Article
            c.BindJSON(&article)
            ins, err := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO articles(title,content) VALUES(?,?)")
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            ins.Exec(article.TITLE, article.CONTENT)
            c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"status": "ok"})
        })
        // add response to OPTIONS
        api.OPTIONS("/post", func(c *gin.Context) {
            c.Header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            c.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            c.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")
            c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"status": "ok"})
        })
```